# Unique identifier for peripheral BLE device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy

So I have peripheral `BLE` device and I need some identifier for it to later share with another iPhone. Example I connect with `iPhone` 'A' to peripheral. `iPhone` 'A' saves peripheral's identifier to database and later I easily can take `iPhone` 'B' and connect to the peripheral found by this identifier.

Now there is `UUID` what changes for every `iPhone-peripheral` connection, but `MAC 
Address` is not available. What could you suggest?

Comment: Yeah that's a problem l faced too while working with iOS 9.0. The identifier used to remain same on all the devices till iOS 8.0. Still looking for an answer.

Comment: Do you use the EAAccessoryManager to find the peripheral? If you do check all EAAccessory properties if you can work with one of these. (modelNumber, serialNumber, name....)

Comment: unless your peripheral provides some sort of unique identifier via a GATT attribute I don't think there is any solution

Comment: ...such as Serial Number from the Device Information Service

Comment: You could implement your own read-only profile/characteristic that contains a unique identifier?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but it is still a problem. For now our team decided that we will do the easy way and will make different peripheral names(ended with random combination).. Yep, one variant was to make char profile as Zimano mentioned. Peripheral developer wasnt sure about GATT attribute, that's why we chose to make unique names. Maybe not so secure, but will get back to this question ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not manufacture the peripheral yourself then you can not uniquely identify peripherals across different iOS devices. This is exactly how Apple wants it to be since it means that developers can't track user's locations or movement patterns based on device addresses. It would be a privacy concern.

If you manufacture the peripheral yourself then you can do pretty much whatever you want. For example: Use a custom Service uuid, add uuid to manufacturer data in advertisement, set unique advertisement names, etc etc..  But if the core purpose of all this is to track your user then I would guess that Apple might deny your submission.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and many thread like [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/8442) say you cannot obtain MAC address by CoreBluetooth. I want to connect to a BLE peripheral (I mean open and connectable peripheral) and store some information on a database so that a different iPhone can read the same database and use the informations when it connects to the same kind of BLE peripheral. For now I rely on the device name, obtained like this:

```
-(void)addDiscoveredDevice:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    NSString * name = [peripheral name];
}
```

because `NSString * uuid = [[peripheral identifier] UUIDString];` gives me different results on different iOS devices.

Therefore, let's say my first problem is to know how many Apple Watch I have close to my iPhone, the second problem is to know if a given Apple Watch (e.g. John's Apple Watch) is close to my iPhone. Unfortunately this method doesn't work because users (e.g. John) or companies can change the name of their peripherals.

Yes I can rely on a combination of name + service uuid + characteristic uuid but for the same reasons, if the name changes it is useless.
Does anybody found a solution?